# how to access the result of get json response in python

Tags: python, json

hi i have the result for get response for url wchich looks like this

how to access each parameter and assigned to variable

```
{
"resultSet":{
"returncnt":1,
"totalCount:10
},
"result":[
{
"type":"
"id":"436ghffs"
]
}
```

Comment: Answer shows `json.loads()`, but this returns a dict just like `response.json()` from requests library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your response looks incorrect, assuming below is correct response:

```
response = '{"resultSet":{"returncnt":1,"totalCount":10},"result":[{"type":"", "id":"436ghffs"}]}'
```

You can try something like this:

```
import json

response = '{"resultSet":{"returncnt":1,"totalCount":10},"result":[{"type":"", "id":"436ghffs"}]}'

result = json.loads(response)
    
print (result['resultSet']['returncnt'])
```

> Output - 1

You can iterate over each element using "for" and get the values as shown below.

```
for x in result['result']:
    print(x['id'])
```

Hope this helps!